# Retrieving annotated method from attribute constructor

Tags: c#

If I annotate a method of a class with an attribute, I can then retrieve custom attributes for that class and see if it has that attribute or not. For example, I'm building a message-oriented program so I have classes like

```
public class ErrorHandler
{
  [HandleMessage(ErrorHandling.ERROR)]
  private static void OnError(string message, object context, params object[] args)
  {
    Exception e;
    args.Extract(out e);

    Console.WriteLine(e.Message + Environment.NewLine + e.StackTrace);
  }
}
```

At runtime I can do this:

```
public static void RegisterStaticHandlers(Type type)
{
  foreach (var mInfo in type.GetMethods(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static))
  {
    var mAttr = mInfo.GetCustomAttribute<HandleMessageAttribute>();
    if (mAttr != null)
      RegisterInstanceHandler(mAttr.Message, mInfo.CreateDelegate<MessageHandler>());
  }
}
```

(I have some extension methods to simplify the code, they're not relevant now.)

My question is: can I get rid of this `RegisterStaticHandlers` method altogether and register the handler in the attribute constructor?

```
public class HandleMessageAttribute : Attribute
{
  public string Message { get; private set; }

  public HandleMessageAttribute(string message)
  {
    Message = message;

    Messages.RegisterInstanceHandler(message, ... method reference here ...);
  }
}
```

Is there a way to retrieve the method that is annotated by an attribute in the attribute constructor, instead of the opposite (and regular) way of having the method and getting its attributes?

[Edited]
I just realized that I can at least do this in the static constructor:

```
static ErrorHandler()
{
  Messages.RegisterStaticHandlers(typeof(ErrorHandler));
}
```

This at least keeps the registration of a class inside that class, which is great as far as I'm concerned :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short, you can't do it from the attribute constructor, When the attribute is constructed it has no access to the target method/class/field/etc to which it is being applied.

From the code, I'm assuming you want the code to auto-register on startup? One way to do this might be to probe your assembly (once, at startup) - enumerate all classes (`foreach(Type type in assembly)`), finding those with candidate error handlers. This reduces the maintenance burden. Another option would be something similar using a configuration file.

Comment: Yes, I am actually doing it in Main() (I'm playing in a console app), I just thought there might be a way to get rid of that altogether. I'm new at attributes :)

Comment: In most cases, attributes are just metadata. You can't really get them to actively *do* anything unless you use tools like PostSharp - but I don't think even that would help here.

Comment: Yes, PostSharp identifies the methods - but not at runtime. It does the weave during the build process. I can't think of a simple way to do the cross-type injection that would be required here.

Comment: (my last comment was in response to a comment that has subsequently been deleted...)

Comment: Yes, sorry about that - I realized that it's identifying them at build time and deleted it.